# Alternative to swift build --clean?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

So it used to be that from the command line, `swift build --clean` would clean the build by removing the `.build` directory. You could also pass `--clean=dist` to get rid of the packages as well.

I just upgraded to Swift 4 and these are apparently gone. Has it been rolled into a subcommand or something? Can anyone point me to some docs on this? I couldn't find them...

Actually, I couldn't find docs on the subcommands at all. I know `swift run` and `swift package` were introduced. Anyone know where a complete documentation of these and other commands are? I find bits and pieces described in various places, but haven't found the complete doc (that hopefully exists somewhere)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`swift build --clean` has been replaced with `swift package clean` in swift 4. We made that change here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2082

Documentation for stuff like this should be at https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md, but it's lacking in some respects. We've just filed [an issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6346) to track that:

I also went ahead and filed:

[Swift usage message should mention swiftpm commands](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6348)

[SwiftPM command usage messages should mention other top-level commands](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6347)

Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: Is it safe to delete the `.build` in your swift package?